# Couldn't delete directory with specific character or long filename in Ubuntu

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

My ec2 is getting the redundant files on my Server `wp-content`.

I have tried it in terminal which like `rm "<?php"` or `rm "<?php\n"` but it didn't work. Replace a single quote for a double quote still not work for me,`rm '<?php'`.
It always shows this message:

**error log**

```
-bash: ?phpn: No such file or directory
```

**Screenshot on terminal**

[image]

Updated:

I saw the way on the `DOS` but not the similar with `ls` prefix. There is another solution to generate shorter filename.

[Can’t Delete Files With Long Filenames? Fix-It In Just 5 Seconds](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/cant-delete-long-filenames/)

Although I solve the problem, But I still couldn't delete the file with specific characters and long filename. When I place `ls -b` that so many `\n` on the monitor. Even use the single quote or slash, it's didn't matter.

Literally, copy the folder and remove the native completely is the true east way.

Answer (score 0):

`<`, `?` and `\` are all special characters to the shell. When you quote using `"` the shell tries to interpret these special characters, leading to an evaluated file name that doesn't exist (in this case).

To remove these files you'll need to quote them using `'` (the single quote). This will quote the string, and tell the shell not to perform any evaluation on the quoted string.

i.e. `rm '<?php' '<?php\n'`

Comment: @RachChen can you post the output of an `ls` on the directory in question?